# is there any way to overwrite select event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i'm using jquery ui auto-complete i would like the reuslts to not insert into input but to go to page that link it if that make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write your own function inside the `select` property of autocomplete to redirect

```
select: function( event, ui )
{
   location.href = ui.item.link;
   return false;
}
```

you have to set a field representing the link where to redirect in your json result. On the example above `link`.

Json ouptut would be:

```
{
   "label" : "your_label",
   "value" : "your_value",
   "link"  : "your_link"
}
```

Comment: sorry im new jquery any example how to redirect

Comment: i've updated my answer with the actual redirect instead of the comment